# Resource does not contain a Definition for Id - c# Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, resources

I am trying to get an `Array` from the `Strings.xml` via the below command:

```
        string[] menuItems = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.menu);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
       'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Array'
```

Also I am getting the same type of error for the following line:

```
    TextView webAddress = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTourUrl);

'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Id'
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the `Resource.Designer.cs` file, but I am not sure how to fix it...

**UPDATE 1:**

These are the Options to fix it:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a wild guess: your `Resource` class does not containt neither `static Array`, nor `static Id` classes.

Comment: And how would I add this?  Thanks

Comment: Please See update

Comment: You add it in the same way yopu add whatever else is in your `Resource` class. You want to use it, then _you_ should now what it is and what it should do. Also add a `menu` property to your `Resource.Array` class while you're at it, and a 'txtTourUrl' to your 'Resource.Id' object.

Comment: It is ok, there was a problem with an ID inside my `Main.axml` which was causing a Rebuild Error.
But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

***For those of you who may have the same problem...***

The reason it was not Rebuilding is because there was an error in my Main.axml file where an object / widget id was: `android:id="@android:id/ list"` Notice the **Space** before the **ID** name...

This causes an error with rebuilding and was unable to generate a class for the `Resource.Id` in Resources.

Just remove any **Spaces** or any **Symbols** that may cause the error and **Rebuild Solution** again.